# How to loop through multiple array based on foreign key selection

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create a django react app. I am trying to fetch datas from django to react. I am stuck where i need to loop through multiple arrays.

This is my serializer.py

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description')


class TechnologiesAndFrameworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TechnologiesAndFramework
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'service')
```

This is my models.py

```
 class Service(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=256)
    description = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

 class TechnologiesAndFramework(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=256)
    description = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=256)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

This is my views.py

```
  class ServiceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
      queryset = Service.objects.all()
      permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]


   class TechnologiesAndFrameworkViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      serializer_class = TechnologiesAndFrameworkSerializer
      queryset = TechnologiesAndFramework.objects.all()
      permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

So at backend, services model has

- Frontend
- Backend
- Deployment

And my TechnologiesAndFramework has

- Django
- React JS
- Docker
- Wagtail
- Bootstrap
- Postgres

I want to loop through TechnologiesAndFramework based on the Services.

So the output should be like this.

1. Frontend

   - React JS
   - Wagtail
   - Bootstrap
2. Backend

   - Django
   - Postgres
3. Deployment

   - Docker

How can i achieve this format?

Currently this is how my react code looks like

```
const [service, setService] = useState([]);
  const [framework, setFramework] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/work/service")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setService);
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/work/f&t")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setFramework);
  }, []);

  <div className="progress-bars">
            {framework &&
              service &&
              framework.map((item, index) => {
                console.log(framework)
                return (
                  <>
                    <h1>{service[item]}</h1>
                    <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                  </>
                );
              })}
          </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changing your .then methods into --> .then(response => setService(response))

Comment: The solution suggested by Radwan Abu-Odeh works for me. Thanks @nir shabi for replying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django, if there is a **1-M relationship** between two models, Django adds an attribute so you the **1 Model** to access the **M-related** objects, it always comes with the name `x_set` where `x -> the model name lowercase`, and you also can rename it so you can access it with proper name.

So what I would suggest is for you to rename the attribute in your `models.py`:

```
...

 class TechnologiesAndFramework(models.Model):
    ...
    # like this, just add related_name attribute.
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='technologies')
....
```

> Now do `makemigrations`, and `migrate`

and now after you add the `related_name` just refer to it in your `ServiceSerializer`, with `SlugRelatedField` like this:

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    technologies = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True, slug_field='title')
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'description', 'technologies')
```

Now your response should look like the following:

```
[
 { 
    "id": "your_service_id", 
    "title": "backend for example", 
    "description": "Your description",
    "technologies": [
        "Django", "Postgres", ...
    ]
 },
....
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Radwan for your help. That was all i needed. Thanks for explaining all the steps as well. But could you let me know what are we actually doing here technologies = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True, slug_field='title'). Sorry i am new to django.

Comment: Yeah sure, so `SlugRelatedField`, is basically a way for DRF to map related strings on a relationshiip, `many=True` indicates that the field is a many relation and the result is going to be mor than one string, and `slug_field` is to tell DRF which field to get the values from in each model object, `read_only=True` is to tell DRF that this field won't accept writing requests on this relation.

Comment: I also recommend you read this documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/, it explains this further in details.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot